# retrain existing word2vec model with new word vectors

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I have trained word2Vec model on a huge corpus using gensim. Then i have tried to find gender bias in the word2vec model. After this I am neutralizing the bias for few specific professional words. Referred the following link for gender de-biasing
https://datascience-enthusiast.com/DL/Operations_on_word_vectors.html
On de-biasing or neutralizing a word, new vector of the specific word is returned. Is it possible to take such new vectors of existing words and retrain the previous model.
Please let me know if there are any techniques of doing so.
Thanks and Regards
AIMC

Comment: Training a model usually uses only a text corpus. So can you be more specific about what you mean by taking the new vectors and retraining the model? What is your expected result? What's wrong with your original training, as adjusted by the method you link? (Why is further retraining desired?)